# Condition in yaml script

Tags: yaml

How can i have an if condition in YAML script below is my sample code.

variables:
global_variable: Test    # this is available to all jobs

parameters:

- name : configs
  displayName: SF Instance
  type: string
  default : Old
  values:

  - Old
  - Older
  - Newer
  - Newest

trigger:

- none

pool:
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true
- task: UseNode@1
- bash:
  ${{ if contains(parameters.configs, 'Old') }}:
  echo $(global_variable)

Comment: YAML doesn't hve if-conditions or variables. Please add information on which tool you are using, e.g. something like Github Workflow, CircleCI, etc.

Comment: Hi tinita I am using github, i want to execute some bash script based on condition in azure devops pipeline using yaml

Comment: if(displayName=='Older'){ some bash script} if(displayName=='New'){ some bash script}